# Reflect and make Axios request in the browser's URL

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, axios, vue-router

## What I'm looking for

Bit of JavaScript logic help; although, I am not sure what I will need to do via Vue Router. Not looking exactly for the answer, but more pointed in the right direction (I'm not even sure I'm phrasing this question correctly).

## Problem

I have been making API requests with Axios (no problem there). I have a JWT token in the requests’ headers. However, (never done this before) I now need to have the search params the user entered in the browser’s URL when they make a request to share the link to their coworkers which will route to the same page with the same options entered/selected and the API request called with those query params.

What I really don’t know is:

- A. What’s the best way to make an API request on route (loading the url with query params)? The route of the page does NOT match the corresponding API endpoint Url.
- B. How do I get the users’ entered/selected data into the browser’s URL?
- C. Do I need to modify my route objects for those pages to still route correctly even if there is now a query string?

## Solution

(Must be purely a frontend solution - I’m using the whole vue ecosystem)

Comment: To clear up something - I need to put the request's params in the path in a query string format.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what I need to do:

### A

The project is not server-side rendered; therefore, I need to parse the URL on Vue's `created` and make a request with the params in the query string. This will seem like the URL caused a API request.

### B

Simply append Axios' request query string to the URL, which I believe is cosmetic and should be fine.

### C

I'm not sure, but will play around with it.